# Errno 2 file not found when calling a function from a different .py file

Tags: python, import, module, ioerror

I made a function that reads from a file and saves it's data in an array.

This function is in `Posts.py`:

```
index = 'Forum/Topics/index.txt'

def loadTopicNames():
    with open(index, 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        for row in data:
            row = row.replace('\n', '')
            topicNames.append(row)
```

This function works, doesn't have problems with the file location. But when I import the `Posts.py` module in my `Forum.py` module, and execute it from `Forum.py`, I get this error:

```
with open(index, 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Forum/Topics/index.txt'
```

Here is the relevant code from `Forum.py`:

```
import Posts
Posts.loadTopicNames()
```

Note: I found some solutions on stackoverflow already, but they mostly include making the path absolute, which is not an option here.
`Posts.py` and `Forum.py` are in the same folder.

This is sort of a representation of where the files are in the project:

Project/Forum.py

Project/Posts.py

Project/Forum/Topics/index.txt

Project/otherStuff...

Edit: found the problem... The working directory for the Forum.py wasn't right, and that was the reason it messed everything up. It had wrong working directory because when I first made the module, I made it in a wrong folder. Then when I realized my mistake, I just copied it to the right place, but the working directory stayed the same...

Comment: I don't think that the code is as much an issue as the file access.  The Python run-time system is telling you that it can't find that file from its current working directory.  Try using the `os` package to list `Forum`, then `Forum/Topics`.

Comment: I'm a bit new to python, I generally know what `os` is, but I'm having no luck on my own to implement your advice. Should I use `os.open()` or something else?

Comment: I saw your note, but can you check whether it works if you set the absolute path?

Comment: @tural Tried it, it works with absolute path. No errors pop up

Comment: a tree structure of your project would help.

Comment: Where is the `index.txt` file relative to the script(s)?

Comment: @Gang I edited the post, does that represent what you asked for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work only if you run `python Forum.py` in the same directory in which the `Forum` directory lives.

**UPD:**
I recreated your case on my laptop, and everything works fine. Please check the code:

Posts.py:

```
index = 'Forum/Topics/index.txt'

def loadTopicNames():
    with open(index, 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        for row in data:
            print(row)
```

Forum.py:

```
import Posts
Posts.loadTopicNames()
```

index.txt:

```
test text
```

Project directory:

```
$ ls -R
Forum     Forum.py  Posts.py

./Forum:
Topics

./Forum/Topics:
index.txt
```

Run & output:

```
$ pwd
/Users/myuser/Forum
$ python Forum.py 
test text
```

Comment: It is, Forum.py and Posts.py are in the same folder. And this function works when called from Posts.py

Comment: It's clear that they are in the same folder. From which folder do you run `Forum.py`?

Comment: From Project folder(The project folder is also called Forum, but I'm calling it Project folder not to confuse it with Forum/Forum folder)

Comment: @kulijana Please, check my updates. It seems that you do something wrong while running the script. BTW did you set some special `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Will do this when I get home, thanks for the effort. I will inform you how it went.

Comment: This is strange, when copying the relevant methods and modules to a new project, everything works just like it works when you tested it. I will look in deeper on why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the effort man, and for the tip about paths, what a silly mess up on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to pass the path to the loadTopic function as a parameter, and passing it on the call in Forum.py

That way you don't have the absolute path hardcoded on the load module.